# Running express only on one route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mithril.js

I am trying to make an app that has a node js express backend serving as the API. I only want express to run on "/api" routes, as I want my MVC framework (mithril js) to handle the client side routing.

I also want to use the pathname route mode with mithril instead of having the hash or question mark symbol in the url (see [here](http://mithril.js.org/routing.html)), the problem with this is as soon as you navigate to any route defined in the mithril router express picks it up and says there is nothing there. Is there a way to tell express to only watch for "/api" routes? Here is my mithril routing code:

`m.route(document.body, "/", {
    "/": Home,
    "/list/:listId": ListSingle
});`

And here is my express api routing code:

`app.get('/api', function(req, res) {
  res.json({test: "Working"});
});`

I am currently using the express.static to serve the client side files.

`app.use("/", express.static('public'));`

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? It's difficult to answer the question if one cannot see your code.

Comment: @gnerkus I have updated to include examples :)

Answer (score 0):

You will want Express to render everything under the 'API' route and control the rest client side with Mithril.

It can be done using a Wildcard on the route. Something like this:

```
app.get('/api*', function(req, res) { res.json({test: "Working"}); });
```

Comment: thanks for the response. The only problem then is if I go to any other route such as "/list/123" express still gives an error that it can't find it. I need a way so that it only watches stuff on the /api routes but nothing else. Is this possible?

Comment: I have come up with a sort of solution. If I create the '/list/:id' route in express and send over the same static files, mithril shows the correct route. The only problem now is the page reloads in between route changes but this does not need to happen with mithril. My question now is: is there a way to stop express reloading the page in between route changes?

Comment: If you look at this Boiler plate, it seems the ordering of the specific routes and the '/' catch-all route is important. Maybe try laying it out as suggested here: https://github.com/Concatapult/node-catapult/blob/master/server/index.js

Comment: Yes that does work with the different routes but the page reloads in when you navigate to a new route. I think this has something to do with express?

Comment: Except for the initial request, how can express pick up a mithril route? Have you looked into why it doesn't stay clientside?